# Adjusting Scale for time series using facet wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, facet-wrap, xscale

I have 15 minute interval water temperature data from 27 environmental stations within a Bay. I have calculated and plotted the daily average temperature for the whole Bay. I used facet_wrap to plot them by year: 2015, 2016 and 2017. But there are outlier points after December for both 2015 and 2016 (see below). Is there a way to only show data from January until December, and cut out  those December outliers? [image].

My data

```
> head(tempdat)
  station    sampletime_15min temp_c X station1 type     lat       lon depth_ft active..starting.20170524. Notes ID2  Easting Northing
1     d01 2016-01-26 13:15:00 27.605 1      d01   O2 18.3355 -64.98416       45                         no         1 290318.6  2028447
2     d01 2016-01-26 13:30:00 27.487 1      d01   O2 18.3355 -64.98416       45                         no         1 290318.6  2028447
3     d01 2016-01-26 13:45:00 27.479 1      d01   O2 18.3355 -64.98416       45                         no         1 290318.6  2028447
4     d01 2016-01-26 14:00:00 27.471 1      d01   O2 18.3355 -64.98416       45                         no         1 290318.6  2028447
5     d01 2016-01-26 14:15:00 27.445 1      d01   O2 18.3355 -64.98416       45                         no         1 290318.6  2028447
6     d01 2016-01-26 14:30:00 27.462 1      d01   O2 18.3355 -64.98416       45                         no         1 290318.6  2028447
            Area       Date
1 Airport runway 2016-01-26
2 Airport runway 2016-01-26
3 Airport runway 2016-01-26
4 Airport runway 2016-01-26
5 Airport runway 2016-01-26
6 Airport runway 2016-01-26
```

My code

```
 tempdat_pre<-readRDS("Data/mnb_temp_all_20171117_QC.rds")
    #tempdat_pre<-tempdat_prep
    station<-read.csv("Data/Enviro_stations_area.csv")

    tempdat_p1<-merge(tempdat_pre, station)
    tempdat_p1$Date<-(as.Date(tempdat_p1$sampletime_15min))
    tempdat_p1 = tempdat_p1[!tempdat_p1$Date<"2015-01-01",]


    #Calculate averages
    tempdat<-tempdat_p1

    daily<-tempdat%>% 
            group_by(Date) %>%
            dplyr::summarise(avgtemp=mean(temp_c))
    daily

    daily$Date<-as.POSIXct(daily$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d", tz="UTC")
    daily<-as.data.frame(daily)

    daily$Date<-as.POSIXct(daily$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d", tz="UTC")
    daily$Year<-format(as.Date(daily$Date), "%Y")
    daily = daily[!daily$Date<"2015-01-01",] # to remove 2014 dates in case. 

    #PLOTS

    dtplot<-ggplot(daily,aes(x = Date,y = avgtemp)) + 
            #geom_point() +
            geom_line(colour="red", size=1.5)+
            #scale_colour_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "green" , high = "red", midpoint = 16) + 
            #geom_smooth(color = "red",size = 1) +
            scale_x_datetime(name="Date", date_breaks="1 months", labels=date_format(format="%b"))+
            #scale_y_continuous(limits = c(5,30), breaks = seq(5,30,5)) +
            #theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
            ggtitle ("Daily average water temperature in Brewer's Bay, St. Thomas, USVI") +
            xlab("Date") +  ylab ("Average Temperature ( ºC )")+
            facet_wrap(~Year, scales='free_x', ncol=1, nrow=3)+
            theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10),
                  axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold"))
    dtplot
```

Comment: add `limits=c(min, max)` in `scale_x_datetime` or filter your data befor plotting.

Comment: I just tried putting limits=c(Jan, Dec), and it gave me this error: Error in continuous_scale(aesthetics, name, identity, breaks = breaks,  : 
  object 'Jan' not found

Comment: Please revise your question by deleting unneseccary code and providing a reproducible example using `dput()`. Otherwise I can't help.

Comment: That "object 'Jan' not found" error is because it's expecting a date. Try putting dates in the limits. This should be easy enough for folks to help with if you `dput` your data